# Is this equivalent to D3DXVec3TransformNormal?

Tags: opengl, directx, porting

I was porting some code from DirectX to OpenGL.
I have the following code:

```
glm::mat4 rotation(1.0f);
rotation = glm::rotate(rotation, degrees, m_up);
m_look  *= rotation;
```

where `rotation` is a `mat4` and `m_look` is a `vec3`. I wanted to know if the last line here,

```
m_look  *= rotation;
```

has the same effect as

```
D3DXVec3TransformNormal( &m_look, &m_look, &rotation );
```

in DirectX? If not, then what would be the correct alternative?

Comment: I can't even find an overload of *= for vec3 taking a mat4 on the left in the snapshot of 0.96. Which version of GLM are you using, and what features (via #define, etc) have you enabled?

Comment: Maybe the mat4 is casted into a vec3 to do that?

Comment: There's no sane way to cast a 4x4 matrix to a 3-component vector. Did that *= ever compile for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got my answer:

The mat4 simply applies a rotation to the vec3, and that rotation information is stored only in the 3x3 part of that mat4, so i can safely cast the mat4 to a mat3 and multiply with the vec3 to get things going, something like

```
m_look = mat3(rotation)*m_look;
```

That would give me what i wanted. I can then normalize my vec3.